# knockout javascript hide controls, move next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, knockout.js

This question is a kind of a two-parter really. Firstly I have part of an application that I think wants splitting into parts as its quite complicated. The majority of the application uses knockout so I'm presuming I should continue using this. What will happen is settings/data is going to be recorded as each page is moved through, kind of similar to when you install something, you click next a page is displayed you click next again etc. You can also click previous and go back and change things. My question is would it be correct to store all this process in knockout as json data and then send all this data back to the database once the user is at the end and hits save, or should I use separate actual pages?

The second question is more of a begging question, would anyone be able to demonstrate how I can do this, say with js fiddle. So to elaborate a little more:
- page 1 select from three values, click next
- page 2 select from dropdown boxes, click next
- page 3 select date and enter value in textbox, click next 
- page 4 user checks all data entered and clicks submit
As each page is moved through I guess I should hide each control that's not required. I have done some of the knockout js examples from the main site, and it kind of makes sense but am not really sure where I should be starting with this example.

Any help gratefully received :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in something that is demonstrated in the Knockout documentation on the computed observables page. You can use an observable to store the current page, for example a number, and then increase and decrease that number with 'next' and 'back' buttons.

Each page can be shown and hidden by wrapping the content inside some virtual knockout elements. For example:

```
<!--ko if: step() == 0-->
    <div>First page content...</div>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko if: step() == 1-->
    <div>Second page content...</div>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko if: step() == 2-->
    <div>Third page content...</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

On each page have controls that are data-bound to various observable properties so the viewmodel is populated as the user navigates through. On the final page, or when you are ready to finish then simply pull all the values into a JSON object for the database.

I have included a snippet that demonstrates this behaviour (albeit not in a very pretty way). The full source that I am using/referencing is here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html

```js
function AppData() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('John');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Burns');
    this.prefix = ko.observable('Dr.');
    this.computedLog = ko.observable('Log: ');
    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var value = this.prefix() + " " + this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        // Normally, you should avoid writing to observables within a pure computed 
        // observable (avoiding side effects). But this example is meant to demonstrate 
        // its internal workings, and writing a log is a good way to do so.
        this.computedLog(this.computedLog.peek() + value + '; ');
        return value;
    }, this);
 
    this.step = ko.observable(0);
    this.next = function () {
        this.step(this.step() === 2 ? 0 : this.step()+1);
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new AppData());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!--ko if: step() == 0-->
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="textInput: firstName" /></p>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko if: step() == 1-->
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="textInput: lastName" /></p>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko if: step() == 2-->
    <div>Prefix: <select data-bind="value: prefix, options: ['Mr.', 'Ms.','Mrs.','Dr.']"></select></div>
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
<!--/ko-->
<p><button type="button" data-bind="click: next">Next</button></p>
<div class="log" data-bind="text: computedLog"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, certainly helps me on my learning journey :)